# Is this server solution optimal?

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpserver

I created device which is receiving data from sensors (about 80k samples / s) and send them through TCP / IP to my PC application. The problem is that sometimes my device loses some data. I suppose it's caused because when I am sending data through TCP/IP processor need some time to do that and then he is not receiving data from sensors for a while. I have noticed that when I am collecting some data before sending its happens less often so I am sending data when data.Length is above 30000. Thanks for yours suggestions.
There is my server code:

```cs
while (true)
{
    if (ClientIsConnected==1)
    {
        value = Convert.ToString(sensor1.Read(0)); ; // Publish the return value 

        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        long elapsedTicks = currentDate.Ticks - startDate.Ticks;
        TimeSpan elapsedSpan = new TimeSpan(elapsedTicks);
        time = Convert.ToString(elapsedTicks / 100);

        data.Append("[" + value + " " + time + "]" + "/n");
        if (data.Length > 30000)
        {
            serverTcp.Send(socket, Convert.ToString(data));
            data.Clear();
        }
    }   
}
```

Edit two diffrent threads code:

```cs
object msg = null;

if (ClientIsConnected==1)
{
    var threadTcp = new Thread(() =>
    {
        server.Send(socket, Convert.ToString(data));
    });

    var threadReadAdc = new Thread(() =>
    {
        value = Convert.ToString(Sensor1.Read(0)); ; // Publish the return value
      
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        long elapsedTicks = currentDate.Ticks - startDate.Ticks;
        TimeSpan elapsedSpan = new TimeSpan(elapsedTicks);
        time = Convert.ToString(elapsedTicks / 100);

        data = data.Append("[" + value + " " + time + "]" + "\n");
        if (data.Length > 30000)
        {
            msg = Convert.ToString(data);
            data.Clear();
        }
    });
    
    threadReadAdc.Start();
    threadTcp.Start();
}
```

Comment: I assume the sensor in question only gives a reading at the point of asking (it doesn't buffer?), if so, you need a thread that's dedicated to reading at a fixed interval and buffering the results, and one that's dedicated to sending the buffered results either on a schedule or at a threshold number of readings. You need to buffer the data on behalf of the sensor.

Comment: Yes the sensor is reading only at the point of asking. So I have to create two different threads. First must be responsible for reading data and the second one for the sending?

Comment: @Charleh thanks for you answer I created two diffrent threads.I added my new code as edit. Can you please explain me what I am doing wrong now? How can I synchronize these threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use something like `BlockingCollection<string>` here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-5.0

You can setup a collection of strings, in one thread write to the collection and in the other thread read. The read can store the results in a buffer and send via TCP when the buffer is full enough (or enough time has elapsed - that's up to you).

The blocking collection is threadsafe, and reading will block until there is something to read.

e.g.

```cs
var data = new BlockingCollection<string>();

Task taskWrite = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while(true)
    {
        var sensorReading = Convert.ToString(sensor1.Read(0)); // Do your string time/formatting here too - I left it off for clarity
        data.Add(sensorReading);
    }
});

Task taskRead = Task.Run(() => {
    var buffer = List<string>();

    while(true)
    {
        if(buffer.Count > 30000) 
        {
            // Grab contents of buffer and send via TCP
            server.Send(socket, String.Join("\n", buffer));
            buffer.Clear();
        }
        else 
        {
            // Consume the next sensor value from the collection
            buffer.Add(data.Take());
        }
    }
});
```

You can also set a bounds on the blocking collection if you want to ensure that you aren't filling up memory with values (if you are reading much faster than you are writing for example).

Comment: Thank you so much, I learned a lot from yours answers. You helped me to understanding how the multithreading work's. Unfortunately, I am still losing data, but it is no longer the server's fault. I will check client side now.